Cookie Get cleared for some fraction of section when reload window
const options = {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    overwrite: true,
    sameSite: "none",
  };

  res
    .status(200)
    .cookie("accessToken", accessToken, options)
    .cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, options)
    .json({
      status: "success",
      message: "User Logged in Successfully",
     data
    });

These are my cookieoptions and response to set cookies
I attempted to use the cookie to log the user in. I retrieve user data and log the user in using a token that is saved in cookies. The token is lost for a little moment every time I reload the page. When the token is deleted, the page is returned to the login page; eventually, the token is restored and the home page is displayed once more.
I don't want the token to be destroyed with a page refresh, not even for a nanosecond. How do I make that right?

I have posted my answer.Please check and let me know.

Hey, Have you tried the solution?what is your feedback?

Hi, Is the issue still persisting ?

Have you checked the application and network tab?
How about you take out the overwrite

Well  You can do it by using either maxAge or expires into your const option = {...
maxAge :- option for setting the expiry time relative to the current time in milliseconds.
expires :- Expiry date of the cookie in GMT. If not specified or set to 0, creates a session cookie.
By using maxAge you can set like this.
const options = {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  overwrite: true,
  sameSite: "none",
  maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 1 day in milliseconds
};

By using expires you can set like this.
const expires = new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 1 day from now
const options = {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  overwrite: true,
  sameSite: "none",
  expires: expires
};

Both methods will help you increase the expiration time of your cookies, ensuring they persist across page reloads.
For more information of Cookie you can visit the official express docs as a reference given below.
https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.cookie
